# push notification error while sending push notification from the MDM server in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, nsnotifications

I am working on a mobile device management system and my push notification isn't working. My Code is

```
//$apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = 'PushCert.pem';

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'my-device-token'; //I have replaced my actual token here

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
//stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $error $errorString" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

I get an error like : `Failed to connect: 0` and if I do `var_dump($fp)` it gives me `bool(false)`. What can be the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Provide the Host Information.
$tHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$tPort = 2195;

// Provide the Certificate and Key Data.
$tCert = 'ck.pem';

// Provide the Private Key Passphrase (alternatively you can keep this secrete
// and enter the key manually on the terminal -> remove relevant line from code).
// Replace XXXXX with your Passphrase
$tPassphrase = '1234';

// Provide the Device Identifier (Ensure that the Identifier does not have spaces in it).
// Replace this token with the token of the iOS device that is to receive the notification.
$tToken = 'YOUR DEVICE TOKEN';

// The message that is to appear on the dialog.
$tAlert = 'You have a LiveCode APNS Message';

// The Badge Number for the Application Icon (integer >=0).
$tBadge = 8;

// Audible Notification Option.
$tSound = 'default';

// The content that is returned by the LiveCode "pushNotificationReceived" message.
$tPayload = 'APNS Message Handled by LiveCode';

// Create the message content that is to be sent to the device.
$tBody['aps'] = array (
    'alert' => $tAlert,
    'badge' => $tBadge,
    'sound' => $tSound,
    );
$tBody ['payload'] = $tPayload;

// Encode the body to JSON.
$tBody = json_encode ($tBody);

// Create the Socket Stream.
$tContext = stream_context_create ();
stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $tCert);

// Remove this line if you would like to enter the Private Key Passphrase manually.
stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $tPassphrase);

// Open the Connection to the APNS Server.
$tSocket = stream_socket_client ('ssl://'.$tHost.':'.$tPort, $error, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $tContext);

// Check if we were able to open a socket.
if (!$tSocket)
    exit ("APNS Connection Failed: $error $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

// Build the Binary Notification.
$tMsg = chr (0) . chr (0) . chr (32) . pack ('H*', $tToken) . pack ('n', strlen ($tBody)) . $tBody;

// Send the Notification to the Server.
$tResult = fwrite ($tSocket, $tMsg, strlen ($tMsg));

if ($tResult)
    echo 'Delivered Message to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Could not Deliver Message to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the Connection to the Server.
fclose ($tSocket);
?>
```

try this code...

if you crate password for PushCert.pem then uncomment this line

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
```

and put password in $passphase